# Does async pipe subscriptions still unsubscribe for Ionic Routing?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

**BACKGROUND:** I'm currently working on a mobile app that uses Promises and I'm exploring RxJS' Observables to replace all existing promise API calls.
My understanding for async pipe is that it automatically unsubscribes when the `ngOnDestroy` is triggered. Since I am using [Ionic Routing](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle) it does not trigger the `ngOnDestroy` it can only trigger `ionViewWillLeave` once I navigated to other page.

**CODE:**
I implemented an async pipe in my html template that looks like this:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="accounts$ | async as accounts; else loadingData">
  <app-account-card *ngFor="let account of accounts" [account]="account"></app-account-card>
</ng-container>

<!-- SKELETON -->
<ng-template #loadingData>
  <app-skeleton-account-card></app-skeleton-account-card>
</ng-template>
```

I have an `account.service.ts` that returns an `Observable<Account[]>`:

```
getAccountsObserver(): Observable<Account[]> {
try {
        return from(this.getSessionID()).pipe(
            switchMap(sessionId => this.http.get<Account[]>(`${URLS.accounts}${ENDPOINTS.accBalance}${sessionId}`))
        );
    } catch (e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

For my `account.component` I simply declared a variable `accounts$`:

```
accounts$: Observable<Account[]>;

  constructor(
    private accountProvider: AccountProvider
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.accounts$ = this.accountProvider.getAccountsObserver();
  }
```

**QUESTION:** Does the Async Pipe still unsubscribes? If no, how can I unsubscribe to it? Is Async Pipe still a best way to display a data from the API or do I need to find a different approach in my case?

Comment: in case page is still in navigation stack (page above page...) then ngDestroy will not trigger unless the previous page is terminated... to terminate it u can use this.router.navigateByUrl('url', { replaceUrl: true }); but this could not work in case u need to go back to ur prev page... so better solution is go and do as this say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription but still not sure if its the best case since i believe best solution is to set the unsubscribe function in ur service and call it when u want.. and ...

Comment: and your approach using observables is not a good approach but i gave u some solutions for ur given but observables and events takes a lot of memory so u get data easier but face much performace issues when ur project expands and face more problems when u try to solve the performance issues when u need to unsubscribe and re subscribe to the event in case u need to navigate back or such things...